# Getting "value must be an integer" when running my Django seeds YAML file

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, yaml, seeding

I'm using Django 2.0, Python 3.7, and MySql 5.5.  I have this model, from which I generated my SQL migration ...

```
class CoopType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name",)
```

I then have this in my seeds_data.yaml file ...

```
- model: maps.cooptype
  pk: 11
  fields:
    name: "Coworking Space"
```

Upon attempting to run my seeds file, it dies with this error ...

```
python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
...
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/maps/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml': ["'{'pk': 11, 'name': 'Coworking Space'}' value must be an integer."]: (maps.coop:pk=1) field_value was '{'pk': 11, 'name': 'Coworking Space'}'
```

I'm confused by the error because it would appear the primary key is an integer so what is the error talking about?

Comment: I have previously got this error when either of the following is true: (a) YAML file is not UTF-8 encoded or (b) YAML file contains a byte order mark (BOM). Try checking/correcting both of those?